# Question in a larger sentence without question mark

Tags: questions

Example:

"I don't understand why she likes him or when she started liking him."

or should it be

"I don't understand why does she like him or when did she start liking him."

?

Should I used the question form for the second sentence? I want to know if you need to use the question form if you are asking a question in a much larger sentence that is not a question itself.

I want to know if I can ask "I don't understand Why he/she did/wanted something" without question form.

"Why you did this" vs "Why did you do this"?

Comment: It would be "I don't understand *why you did this*" because "I don't understand why did you do this" makes a grammatically incorrect sentence.

Answer (score 1):

- The ***interrogative word order***, which we use in normal questions,
  is ***auxiliary + subject + main verb*** except in questions where
  the question word comes as the subject.

Why **does she love** him?

Who **loves** him? (**Who** is the subject)

- In spoken questions or declarative questions, the declarative or
  normal  word order is used, if the sentence is not begun with a
  question word. The question form is actually created in speech by a
  rising intonation.

**You are working** late tonight?

- In ***indirect questions***, the declarative word order is used and
  the sentence ***ends with a full stop***, not with a question mark.

I wondered ***what time the film was starting***.

- However, in formal writing inversion is sometimes used with **verb
  be** in indirect questions after **how**, especially when the subject
  is long.

*I wondered **how** reliable **was the information I had been given**.* (Note: still without the question mark).

(Based on Michael Swan's PEU)

Answer (score 0):

Some sentences are statements—or demands—in the form of a question. They are called rhetorical questions because they don't require or expect an answer. Many should be written without question marks.
**Examples:**
Why don't you take a break.
Would you kids knock it off.
What wouldn't I do for you!

Also, avoid the common trap of using question marks with indirect questions, which are statements that contain questions. Use a period after an indirect question.
Incorrect: 
I wonder if he would go with me?
Correct:
I wonder if he would go with me.